# making Directory in sd card android in one click

Tags: android, file, sd-card

i want to make directory in sd-card in android .And store audio file with in An ordered manner . How can i do this.
Thank you
i have done that but by this code i should make a directory in sd-card..

```
codeaudioFilePath = 
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + 
"/amitaudio/audio.mp3";

File file = new File(filepath,amitaudio); 
if(!file.exists()){ file.mkdirs();  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this is working correctly :-

File amitaudio=new File(audioFilePath);

```
    amitaudio.mkdirs();
```

But i can not made ascending order creation of audio files please tell me ...thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
File file = new File(filepath,/*Your folder name*/);
if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();           
        }
```

Comment: this code is not working for me please explain in this codeaudioFilePath = 
             Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                 + "/amitaudio/audio.mp3"; 
 
  File file = new File(filepath,amitaudio);
  if(!file.exists()){
              file.mkdirs();           
          }